# How do I copy a character array to the clipboard?

Tags: c++, winapi, clipboard

I am trying to get my application to copy a character array to the clipboard so it can be pasted into an IE address bar. I am having an issue with getting this working. This is the code I am working with:

```
HGLOBAL glob = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED,32);
memcpy(glob,array,sizeof(array));
OpenClipboard(hDlg);
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT,glob);
CloseClipboard();
```

Array is declared as:

```
char array[500];
```

This will cause the program to crash. However if I switch out `sizeof(array)` with a number it ok but The only 8 characters are copyied to the clipboard.

Can anyone advise me on how to solve this issue? I am targeting the Win32 API directly, not using MFC.

Comment: Show us the declaration for `array`

Comment: @JohnDiblin I have array declared like this `char array[500];` in the same method.

Comment: Then you've got a problem right there. It is not Unicode text if it's stored in an array of `char`.

Comment: @L337BEAN well there's your answer; you're copying 500 characters into something that only has space for 32.

Comment: memory should be allocated with the `GMEM_MOVEABLE` flag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only allocating 32 bytes of global memory:

```
GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED,32);
```

...and then trying to cram 500 bytes in to a 32 byte bag:

```
memcpy(glob,array,sizeof(array));
```

Change the GlobalAlloc to:

```
GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED,sizeof(array));
```

Further, you are pasting the data as Unicode text (`CF_UNICODETEXT`), but it's not Unicode text.  I would imagine that would cause... problems.

Paste it as plain text instead:

```
SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT,glob);
```

Comment: You are correct. It seems so obvious I don't know how I missed it. You are also correct regarding the `CF_TEXT`. Thank you for your fast informative answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are copying 500 chars (`sizeof(array)`) into a buffer that only has space for 32 chars. All the remaining chars trample over random data and cause the crash.

Answer (score 2):

I created a function to save and load clipboard.

```
#include <Windows.h>
char* LoadClipboard()
{
    static HANDLE clip;
    if(OpenClipboard(NULL))
    {
        clip = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
        CloseClipboard();
    }
    return (char*) clip;
}

void SaveClipboard(char* text)
{
    HGLOBAL global = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED,strlen(text) + 1); //text size + \0 character
    memcpy(global,text,strlen(text));  //text size + \0 character
    if(OpenClipboard(NULL))
    {
        EmptyClipboard();
        SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT,global);
        CloseClipboard();
    }
}
```